# Smaller root of a difference of products of polynomials with integer bounded coefficients

Tags: polynomials, lower-bounds

Is there a positive constant $K>0$ such that
for every polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_4 \in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with coefficients in {-1,0,1}, every positive root $x$ of the polynomial
$$g=f_1f_2-f_3f_4$$
satisfies $x \geq K$, provided that $g$ is not the zero polynomial ?

**Remark:** This seems to be related to the growth of the coefficients of $g$. If $g=\sum a_iX^i$, and $a_k$ is the first non-zero coefficient in this sequence, can we even bound $\frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|}$ ?

Comment: Let h=1+x+...+x^n, f1=1-x-hx^2, f2=1+x-hx^2, f3=1-x+hx^2, f4=1+hx^2.  Then f1 f2 - f3 f4 has a root close to 1/(3+sqrt(7)), or 0.1771, which may be the optimal value of K.